# A confusing question in Royden's Real Analysis

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $I $ be a closed and bounded interval, and $E $ a measurable subset of $I$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Show that there is a step function $h $ on $I $ and a measurable subset $F $ of $I $ for which $h=\chi_E $ on F and $m (I\sim F) <\epsilon $.

Here we assume all sets are subsets of $\Bbb {R} $.

Why can't we have $F=I$?  Clearly I is measurable!

Comment: Will $h$ still be the characteristic function for $E$ on $I$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238944/stuck-on-existence-proofs-involving-measurability-and-simple-functions