# Continuous Approximation on a measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238944/stuck-on-existence-proofs-involving-measurability-and-simple-functions), we have for any measurable $f$ defined on closed and and bounded $I$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exists a step function $h$ defined on $I$ and a measurable set $F$ subset of $I$ such that $|h-f|<\epsilon$ and $m(I \setminus F) < \epsilon$.

I have one exercise from lecture as follows:

For any measurable $f$ defined on closed and bounded intercal $I$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exists a step function $h$ and a continuous function $g$ such that $|f-g|<\epsilon$ and $|f-h|<\epsilon$ except on a set of measure less than $\epsilon$.

I have no idea how to construct such a continuous $h$ that satisfies the requirement above.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: continuous close to step: at each jump, make it continuously slant up/down in a tiny interval.  You can use $2$ $\varepsilon/2$s.

Comment: So for any discontinuities, I define an open interval centered at discontinuites with length $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$?